# Android Maven build gives trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

Following error is showing in **Maven** console everytime I do Project -> Clean. Only the **jar** file is built in the target folder, **apk** file is not getting built. 
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Regards,

Sam.

My development environment is;

- Eclipse Helios
- Android SDK API level 8
- Eclipse ADT 10.0.1
- Maven Integration for Android Development Tools 0.2.5

4/30/11 9:54:07 PM IST: [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\my\workspace\android\android-test-app\src\test\resources
4/30/11 9:54:07 PM IST: [INFO] Not compiling test sources
4/30/11 9:54:07 PM IST: [INFO] Tests are skipped.
4/30/11 9:54:07 PM IST: [INFO] D:\my\android-sdk-my\android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/dx.bat [--dex, --output=D:\my\workspace\android\android-test-app\target\classes.dex, D:\my\workspace\android\android-test-app\target\android-classes]
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] when not building a core library.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] going on.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] It is also often of questionable legality.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] building an application, then be forewarned that your application
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] system. You will be to blame for this problem.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 
4/30/11 9:54:17 PM IST: [INFO] 1 error; aborting

Comment: funny that someone else posted this issue two hours before I discovered it :) I don't have a solution, but I found this thread on the bug: http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=68  It seems to have been a problem for a year now and based on the comments in that thread, I'm not sure why it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: one more note: My errors arose from the inclusion of xpp3 jar dependencies in the google data API and I am not using maven for build

Comment: @jk exclude the dependency then...

Comment: Hi, I have excluded all the dependencies that are reusing, But no luck with that. Any ideas on this issue ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your are using android maven integration, you should add the "provided" scope in your android sdk dependency.

```
<dependency>        
<groupId>com.google.android</groupId>        
<artifactId>android</artifactId>        
<version>2.3.3</version>        
<scope>provided</scope>        
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can exclude implicit dependencies using the exclude-tag. QName seems to be in e.g. the xpp3 package. I solved this problem by adding the following exclusions to my pom (that already contained the dependency to google-api-client-googleapis):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client-googleapis</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you need to find where the conflicting class files come from, run for example:

```
for x in `find ~/.m2/repository/ -name \*.jar`; do jar tf $x|grep QName.class && echo "Found in: $x"; done`
```