# Android on Eclipse - trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I am developing an Android App that uses the Google APIs Client Library for Java version 1.12.0. I have added the jar files to the /libs folder (and not to a new /lib folder). I get the following error during run-time:

Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

I am NOT using Maven though, and all the answers by others seem to make use of Maven.

Android version - 4.1.2 API level 16
Eclipse - Java EE Juno

Any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: Right click on your project select java build path >> Add external libraries and browse to the jar that you want to add.

Comment: I did this, but got 'Class X not found referenced from within Y method' errors

Answer (score 0):

A Best way to add External Jars to your Android Project or any Java project is:

Create a folder called 'libs' into you project root folder
Copy your Jar files to the libs folder
Now right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path, this will create a folder called 'Referenced Library' into you project, and your are done
By do doing like this, whenever you transfer you project to other Computer, you will not miss your libraries which are being referenced to some space on your Hard drive.

Comment: The /libs folder was already there and I added the jar files to it and have added the same to the build path, but I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should put jar in libs folder and then Project -> Properies -> Java Buid Path -> Add JARs -> Select jar of your library from libs folder -> OK.

Comment: Please look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098088/dalvik-vm-error-exception-found-javax-xml-namespace-qname-class) I think it's the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks, this post helped me. I had to delete xpp3-1.1.4c.jar and a couple of other jar files, which my application was not using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got a solution yet. I post this here to help someone in the future with the same problem.

Basically I had to remove "android.jar" from the build path, keeping the "Android X.X" library. Then, clean the project.

This is the [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/539779/Android/Mobile/Ill-advised-mistaken-usage-core)

Answer (score 0):

following here

window->preference->compiler->jre1.6
after do
  project->properties->java build path-> addlibrary->jresystemlibrary->environment->choose your jre

it will solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

You follow this steps to add external jar in your project

Step 1

[image: Step 1]

Step 2

[image: Step 2]

Step 3

[image: Step 3]

Comment: Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

Comment: LogCat has nothing, I have pasted what is there on the console:

Comment: [2012-11-24 08:08:08 - OOProject] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

[2012-11-24 08:08:08 - OOProject] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). ....

Comment: Take a look at this :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843143/android-maven-build-gives-trouble-processing-javax-xml-namespace-qname-class

Comment: The solution is for Android + Maven, I am not using Maven. Also, one post says that the error is because of xpp3 jar dependencies, I deleted the jar file, but that also did not help me. Is there any other way to exclude dependencies? like adding it to an XML file? (the way they do it for Maven)